# Vaadin - Update text of a single header column when it is resized

Tags: vaadin

I am trying to resize the column and add a resizeEventListener to it. This is in a Vaadin grid. 
When the column is resized, I expect that the column that was resized should be updated with the new text that I supply. However, in my case, the grid is updating all the columns of the grid. The rest of the columns should not be touched.

I am using Vaadin 7.6.4 as a simnple eclipse project.
Code is given below:-

```
    grid.addColumnResizeListener(new ColumnResizeListener(){

        private static final long serialVersionUID = -4280346740116267368L;

        @Override
        public void columnResize(ColumnResizeEvent event) {
            String columnName = (String) event.getColumn().getPropertyId();
            TableColumnData tblData = getColumnData(tblDataLst,columnName);

            double colWidth = event.getColumn().getWidth();
            double colMinWidth = event.getColumn().getWidth() / 2 ;



               grid.getDefaultHeaderRow().getCell(columnName).setText(tblData.getShort_name());
               logger.info("call made to resize column="+columnName);





        }

    });
    grid.setImmediate(true);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Intro:** I've just tested this with 7.6.4 using a simple grid with undefined column widths, and if you add a log message in your listener, you will see that the first time a resize event is triggered, all of the columns get resized to auto-calculated sizes. Subsequent events however will only be triggered for the appropriate column, which in my case was `Image`

---

**Source:**

```java
public class MyGridComponent extends VerticalLayout {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyGridComponent.class);

    public MyGridComponent() {
        BeanItemContainer<MyBean> dataSource = new BeanItemContainer<>(MyBean.class);
        Grid grid = new Grid(dataSource);
        addComponent(grid);


        grid.getColumn("image").setRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
        grid.setColumnOrder("image", "name", "surname");

        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(null, "Agent", "Smith"));
        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(null, "There is", "No spoon"));
        dataSource.addItem(new MyBean(null, "The", "One"));

        for (Grid.Column column : grid.getColumns()) {
            log.debug("Column [{}] has width [{}]", column.getHeaderCaption(), column.getWidth());
        }

        grid.addColumnResizeListener(event -> {
            Grid.Column column = event.getColumn();
            log.debug("Column resize event for [{}] was triggered by [{}] with new width [{}]", column.getHeaderCaption(), event.isUserOriginated() ? "user" : "vaadin", column.getWidth());
        });
    }

    public static class MyBean {
        private ExternalResource image;
        private String name, surname;

        public MyBean(ExternalResource image, String name, String surname) {
            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
        }

        public ExternalResource getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
    }
}
```

**Generated log**

```
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Image] has width [-1.0]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Name] has width [-1.0]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Surname] has width [-1.0]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Image] was triggered by [user] with new width [149.171875]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Name] was triggered by [user] with new width [168.703125]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Surname] was triggered by [user] with new width [182.09375]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Image] was triggered by [user] with new width [195.171875]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Image] was triggered by [user] with new width [334.171875]
 com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Image] was triggered by [user] with new width [175.171875]
```

Judging by the description in the [original enhancement/feature ticket](https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/16838) this, may and may not be a bug:

> Resizing a column should not affect the size of other columns and the automatic sizing of columns should be disabled after the user has resized some column (like in Table)

It may be a bug because it triggers a resize for all the columns, but at the same time it may not be a bug because the desired behaviour is to switch from auto-size (-1) to calculated or user defined sizes, which indeed happens.

---

**Workaround:** A quick & dirty workaround would be to manually define sizes for your columns when building the grid, something along the lines of the follosing (please note that you should add the listener only after having defined the sizes, otherwise it will be triggered as well for each `setWidth` call):

```java
    for (Grid.Column column : grid.getColumns()) {
        column.setWidth(100);
        log.debug("Column [{}] has width [{}]", column.getHeaderCaption(), column.getWidth());
    }
```

Which seems to generate the desired behaviour:

```
com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Image] has width [100.0]
com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Name] has width [100.0]
com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column [Surname] has width [100.0]
com.example.grid.MyGridComponent: Column resize event for [Image] was triggered by [user] with new width [133.0]
```

From the various tests that I have done, this seems to happen only when resize is user-triggered. If, for example, one would use `grid.getColumn("image").setWidth(100)`, then the other 2 columns will remain with undefined (-1) widths, and the issue will happen again at the first user-resize. In addition, it seems to happen as long as at least 1 column has an undefined size, which implies that you have to manually set sizes to all the columns in order for this workaround to be effective.

---

**Outro**: I would be very interested to hear some other *more expert* opinions on this matter and whether this initial event should be propagated to the listener or not...

Comment: @jbdundas No problem, glad I could help. However I'm really curious about the developer's point of view regarding this. I wonder whether it would be worth opening a ticket on their tracker to get an _official_ opinion on this matter because I can understand both points of view, but can't decide which should take precedence, and if at all possible I like to avoid such ugly workarounds... Anyways, cheers and happy coding :-)